# Bitcoin user characteristic

Tags: gambling, user-data

I am starting with the execution of internet marketing activities for one Bitcoin gambling site that I owe, and I am trying to figure what best describes owners of bitcoin.

Are there any demographics information available? What sites / habbits dothe bitcoin user have, where does he browse sites online, is he using Bitcoin for gambling purposes etc etc

If someone can help with some insights or useful information I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily you are not the first person trying to figure this out.

According to an online poll, the average user of Bitcoin is a 32.1-year-old “libertarian” male, from a report at [ThinkProgress](http://thinkprogress.org/economy/2014/02/27/3341411/bitcoin-privilege/).

There are some realy detailed Demographics out there:
[Zerohedge.com](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2013-03-10/demographics-bitcoin)
[Simulacrum.cc](http://simulacrum.cc/2013/03/04/the-demographics-of-bitcoin-part-1-updated/)

Comment: Yep I just stubmled upon many results in google search, I can now see some characteristics and it makes sense all together. 

I am in search of all kind of ad networks (CPC, CPM, CPA, Affiliate) if you can suggest some, thank you.